# How to get even distance edge

Tags: modeling, add-on

How to get even distance edge. I tried to inset and scale down and added few loop cuts. I got this result. Which are not even to right and left side.

[image]

[image]

I tried with the straight skeleton addon. Few loops looks even but as i go inside it start getting mess.

All the scale and rotation are applied. Any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: There is an 'even' option for the loop cuts, but it only works on inner sections. As your shape is not even at the base, make even cuts has its limits.

Comment: @lemon got this result with straight skeleton addon : https://imgur.com/a/CXGtr9d